# GWT Java - how to display another external web page within a panel or widget?

Tags: java, gwt

I need a panel or widget whereby I set a URL and that panel/widget displays the web page of the URL inside it. Similar to how WebView and UIWebView work in Android and iOS applications.

Comment: You could user an Iframe. Just create an HTMLPanel with the iframe code inside.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Have added as an answer.

Comment: See also this question: [GWT Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost” from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47862088/4491066).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use an HTMLPanel with an iFrame

```
    HTMLPanel htmlPanel = new HTMLPanel("<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ\" style=\"width:600px; height:600px;\" >Unfortunately this content could not be displayed</iframe>");
    RootPanel.get("mainDiv").add(htmlPanel);
```